# Azure service bus security using asymmetric certificates

Tags: azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

At present, we are creating an AAD application & service bus has been access by client application using service principal & working fine.

But there is new client requirement to use asymmetric certificates to access & post message to azure service bus, is it possible? please confirm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As on Oct 14 2019 Azure Service Bus does not support the use of certificates. You can either do SAS signatures or AAD service prinicpals.